# Optimize rows to columns conversion

Tags: oracle, performance

I have a big Oracle table (around 40 million rows) that looks like this:

```
ID  Name    Question Answer Reason      
3   Name1   1       Yes     blah blah
3   Name1   2       No      NA
3   Name1   3       No      NA
3   Name1   4       Yes     blah2
3   Name1   5       Yes     null
3   Name1   6       Yes     blah3
3   Name1   7       No      null
6   Name2   1       Yes     blah4444
6   Name2   2       No      null
6   Name2   3       Yes     blah3
6   Name2   4       NA      blah5
6   Name2   5       Yes     null
6   Name2   6       Yes     blah6
6   Name2   7       NA      null
```

I need one row per ID i.e. I will need to add columns for each question's answer (there are 7 questions per ID) and each question's reason. I need to make it look like this:

```
ID  Name    Q1     Q1-Reason    Q2    Q2-Reason   Q3    Q3-Reason    etc.
3   Name1   Yes    blah blah    No    null      
6   Name2   Yes    blah4444     No    null
```

My query currently looks like this:

```
select
   A.ID,A.NAME,B1.Q1,B1.Q1-REASON,B2.Q2,B2.Q2-REASON
from
   TABLENAME A
inner join
    (
    select distinct C1.ID,C1.ANSWER as Q1,C1.REASON as Q1-REASON
    from TABLENAME C1
    where C1.QUESTION=1
    ) B1 on B1.ID=A.ID
inner join
    (
    select distinct C2.ID,C2.ANSWER as Q2,C2.REASON as Q2-REASON
    from TABLENAME C2
    where C2.QUESTION=2
    ) B2 on B2.ID=A.ID
...
...
```

However, as the table is huge, this is taking a VERY long time to retrieve the data. Could someone suggest ways to optimize this query? Any help would be appreciated!

I'm on Oracle 10g and SQLDeveloper 4.0.2.15

Comment: Do you really need all those `DISTINCT`? Isn't the `(question, id)` combination unique?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using so many JOINs to get the result, you might get better performance pivoting the data using an aggregate function with a CASE expression.  Oracle 10g doesn't have a PIVOT function so you'd have to use this type of query (aggregate/CASE) if you aren't going to use multiple JOINs on your table.

Since you have a limited number of questions (7), you can easily hard-code the query:

```
select
  id,
  name,
  max(case when question = 1 then Answer end) Q1_Answer,
  max(case when question = 1 then Reason end) Q1_Reason,
  max(case when question = 2 then Answer end) Q2_Answer,
  max(case when question = 2 then Reason end) Q2_Reason,
  max(case when question = 3 then Answer end) Q3_Answer,
  max(case when question = 3 then Reason end) Q3_Reason,
  max(case when question = 4 then Answer end) Q4_Answer,
  max(case when question = 4 then Reason end) Q4_Reason,
  max(case when question = 5 then Answer end) Q5_Answer,
  max(case when question = 5 then Reason end) Q5_Reason,
  max(case when question = 6 then Answer end) Q6_Answer,
  max(case when question = 6 then Reason end) Q6_Reason,
  max(case when question = 7 then Answer end) Q7_Answer,
  max(case when question = 7 then Reason end) Q7_Reason
from tablename
group by id, name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4777/1)

Answer (score -1):

This question is a hardy perennial on the Oracle lists. The PIVOT operator only came in in 11g, so that's no good to you. You might start by looking [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php) (also gives non-PIVOT solutions - oracle-base is an excellent tips and snippets site).

The Oracle forums FAQ has a "How do I convert rows to columns" section [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/9362005#9362005). An interesting application of windowing functions is covered [here](http://www.club-oracle.com/forums/pivoting-row-to-column-conversion-techniques-sql-t144/) (Sys_connect_by_path). You can also use the MODEL clause - covered [here](http://technology.amis.nl/2004/12/16/pivoting-in-sql-using-the-10g-model-clause/). [Here](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/179193/) is also of interest - the Orafaq site is also an excellent site for all things Oracle - they have [forums](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/i/) similar to this one, but focussed exclusively on Oracle - I've found them very good in the past.

As for performance, I suggest that you first asses which methods provide you with the correct answer and then go on to test them for performance. Just as an aside, [this](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php) might also be of interest.